# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify'

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
def josaa_scrape():
    """
    Sample usage: df = josaa_scrape("2018", "1")
    df.info()
    """
    with requests.Session() as s:
        R = s.get(url, headers=headers)
        data = {}

        for key, value in params.items():
            data.update({tag['name']: tag['value'] for tag in BeautifulSoup(R.content, 'lxml').select('input[name^=__]')})
            data[key] = value
            R = s.post(url, data=data)

    table = BeautifulSoup(R.text, 'lxml').find(id = 'GridView1')
    df = pd.read_html(table.prettify())[0]
    df.dropna(inplace = True, how="all")

    return df
```

It is throwing an error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify'. I have check all id's.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This actually means that `BeautifulSoup(R.text, 'lxml').find(id = 'GridView1')` returned nothing.
Fix that line so it will return a table element